# Versioned Solidity Smart Contracts

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am learning Solidity and have confusion on contract upgrade-ability. From my understanding, a deployed smart contract is immutable and cannot be altered. If I need to add additional functionality to a contract, I can have the contract versioned and deploy a new version. But the storage data in the old contract remains as-is.

I have a contract like the below

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.10 <0.7.0;

contract User {

struct UserEntity {
   address userAddress;
   uint8 UserID; 
   string  UserName;
}

UserEntity public _UserEntity;
mapping (address=> UserEntity) UserMapping;

function addUser(address _userAddress, uint8 _UserID, string memory _UserName) public {
   _UserEntity = UserEntity(_userAddress, _UserID, _UserName);
   UserMapping[_userAddress] = _UserEntity;
}

function getUserID(address _userAddress) public view returns(uint8) {
   return(UserMapping[_userAddress].UserID);
}
}
```

If I need to search for the UserID, I can use the getter as above. But if I deploy a new version of the contract, the mapping **UserMapping** is not available. What is the best approach to be able to search the entire storage for the entry that I need? I read somewhere that a NameRegistry might be an option but I am not sure how to implement this. My end goal is to have a UI query this data and contract upgrades should be transparent to the UI

*N.B.* I am using a single deployment of the contract to add multiple users by loading the contract from it's deployed address, creating an externally owned account using web3js and then calling the function **addUser** and passing this EOA as a parameter.

Comment: Looks like an EternalStorage will solve this :) Looking more into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved using EternalStorage. Looking further at more elegant upgrade techniques. But the issue is resolved for now.

Answer (score 1):

**Upgradeable smart contracts**
You can use the OpenZeppelin SDK to create upgradeable smart contracts.
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/sdk/2.5/

OpenZeppelin uses the "unstructured storage" proxy pattern.
See the documentation for details: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/sdk/2.5/pattern

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

*Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin*